# run pig explain command over the entire script in java

Tags: java, apache-pig, sql-execution-plan

I am trying to find the way to run the explain command over the entire pig script in java. 
I was using PigServer but it offers only to do explain over the single query (alias) not the entire script. 
Is there a way to do something like:

```
$ pig -x local -e 'explain -script Temp1/TPC_test.pig -out explain-out9.txt'
```

but from my Java code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use [PigRunner](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/api/index.html?org/apache/pig/PigRunner.html) for this purpose.
E.g:

```
import org.apache.pig.PigRunner;
import org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStats;

public class PigTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        args = new String [] {
                "-x", "local",
                "-e", "explain -script Temp1/TPC_test.pig -out explain-out9.txt"
        };

        PigStats stats = PigRunner.run(args, null);
        //print plan:
        //stats.getJobGraph().explain(System.out, "text", true);
    }

}
```

I found that the following runtime dependencies are needed to avoid *NoClassDefFoundError*:

- [jackson-mapper-asl](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-mapper-asl)
- [antlr-runtime](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.antlr/antlr-runtime)
- [guava](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava)

Comment: great! this will do the work I think! thanks! although I would like to read the script from the internal structure (String or something) but I'll manage somehow.

Comment: is there a way using PigRunner to divert the output messages to the file or custom logger?

Comment: You may redirect the standard output stream, see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut%28java.io.PrintStream%29

Comment: how can we pass params as arg to pigrunner's run method? I want to give some variable value, normally we do it like -p paramname=paramvalue when we run pig script from command line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use org.apache.pig.PigServer to run pig scripts from Java programs:

```
PigServer pigServer = new PigServer(ExecType.MAPREDUCE);
pigServer.registerScript("scripts/test.pig");
Requires 'pig.properties' on classpath.

fs.default.name=hdfs://<namenode-hostname>:<port>
mapred.job.tracker=<jobtracker-hostname>:<port>
Or pass an instance of java.util.Properties to PigServer constructor.

Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("fs.default.name", "hdfs://<namenode-hostname>:<port>");
props.setProperty("mapred.job.tracker", "<jobtracker-hostname>:<port>");
PigServer pigServer = new PigServer(ExecType.MAPREDUCE, props);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: the thing is that I need the execution plan that EXPLAIN command returns... any idea how can I get it in Java for the entire script?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can also use the grunt shell! (I always forget about this.)

On our site, we're using a launcher script which prepares a pig invocation command like follows:

```
$ pig -p param1=foo -p param2=bar script.pig
```

You can use `explain -script` in the grunt shell:

- invoke `pig`
- wrap the script call with `explain`

It looks like:

```
$ pig
grunt> explain -param param1=foo -param param2=bar script.pig
```